# Database Headaches - Mind not working today

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, database-design

I cant seem to get my head around how to create this
Each Bold Letter is a Database Table 
I need this to work with Entity Framework

**Product**

[ Product belongs to one group]
**Product Group - [Computer]**

*[many to many]*

[Group has many items]
[Product belongs to one Group Item]
**Product Group Item - [Hard Drive]**

*[many to many]*

[Group Items has Many Fields]
[Fields does not change for each product only changes for each Group Item]
**Product Group Item Field - [Form Factor]**

[Group Item Fields has many values]
[Field Values Change with each product]
**Product Group Item Field Values - [ 3.5" ]**

I can pretty much get the first 3 to work
my problem is how to do the last two tables
I hope I explained it clear enough 
thanks in advance

[alt text http://myimgs.net/images/cjgo.gif](http://myimgs.net/images/cjgo.gif)

maybe this will help or just hurt who knows

Product = is a harddrive

so:

Group - Computer 
GroupItem - Harddrive

GroupItemField - Form Factor  : GroupItemFieldValue - 3.5"
GroupItemField - Capacity     : GroupItemFieldValue - 600MB 
etc...

but the field value changes for each product of type Harddrive but the field does not

Comment: I can see why you're having trouble.  1) Fix the blank lines so the table name is first and the description follows the table name.  2) Remove the []'s and try using indentation or something clearer.  3) Try drawing a picture and adding that to your question.

Comment: what is your problem ?
What are you trying to achieve ?
What is your problem with the last two tables ?

Comment: +1 to balance the -1 that was done w/o explanation.

Comment: my problem is i cant seem to work out how to place the last two tables, many to many or something else, cause the group items fields do not change for each product but the values do, not sure how else to explain it, but i guess thats part of my problem not understanding

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly... All **products** belonging to the same **group** have the same attributes. You need to define a schema that will allow you to set the values of each of the products?

Comment: Actually, I don't know if the picture helps that much. It does give us your attempt at a solution to the problem you're trying to solve. But I don't think we understand your problem yet. Could you please confirm or deny my guess above?

Comment: yes that would be corrent only thing that will change if the product is of the same type is the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be trying to over-generalise your solution.

It seems to me you want to standardise the information you capture for different kinds of products.

E.g. Hard Drives

```
1  Supplier1   Model 1a   3.5"    600MB
2  Supplier1   Model 1b   3.5"    200GB
3  Supplier2   Model X    2.5"    600MB
```

And you want to represent the attributes in a single table:

```
1 FormFactor   3.5"
1 Capacity     600MB
2 FormFactor   3.5"
2 Capacity     200GB
3 FormFactor   2.5"
3 Capacity     600MB
```

The problem is that over-generalising like this you lose all the data integrity controls that your RDBMS provides.

You may be better off with:

**Product** (*Id, Name, GroupId, Supplier, Model, ...)
**HardDrive** (*Id, FormFactor, Capacity, ...)
**Monitor** (*Id, Resolution, ...)
**Memory** (*Id, Capacity, Speed, ...)

Each of the above product specific tables has an optional-to-one reference to **Product**. With such a design, it becomes impossible to capture **Monitor** attributes for a hard-drive unless you add a **Monitor** row for the product.

That said, if you're willing to forego integrity controls, or manage them yourself in code, then looking at sample data helps to produce your schema. (I'm going to use the terminology of attributes.)

**AttributeValues** (*ProductId, *AttributeId, Value)  -- Note a problem here: what type should Value be?

You will need some way of indicating what attributes are allowed for each Group:

```
HardDrive FormFactor  Req
HardDrive Capacity    Req
Monitor   Resolution  Req
Monitor   Colour      Opt
Memory    Capacity    Req
Memory    Speed       Req
```

**GroupAttributes** (*GroupId, *AttributeId, IsOptional)

Then you need to indicate the group to which a product belongs (so that you can figure out which values need to be filled in)

```
1  Supplier1   Model 1a   HardDrive
2  Supplier1   Model 1b   HardDrive
3  Supplier2   Model X    HardDrive
4  Supplier2   Model M1   Monitor
```

**Products** (*ProductId, Group, SupplierId, ModelNo)

I'm not sure where your GroupItems fit in.

**Relationships**
Products.GroupId -> Groups.GroupId
Products.SupplierId -> Suppliers.SupplierId
GroupAttribute.GroupId -> Groups.GroupId
GroupAttribute.AttributeId -> Groups.AttributeId
AttributeValue.ProductId -> Products.ProductId
AttributeValue.AttributeId -> Attributes.AttributeId

**NOTE**
I've illustrated how you can add columns defining rules for the attribute values. You could do the same for the **Attributes** table where you'd probably at a minimum need to indicate the data-type of the attribute.

You may notice that it won't be long and you'll soon be replicating the meta-data that your RDBMS provides to define tables and columns. The highly generalised solution does have its benefits such as using a simple template mechanism to capture and view products. But it becomes quite a bit more difficult (in code and processing time) to perform other tasks. So I suggest you consider your requirements holistically against the design.

Comment: thank u for sticking with me and find out what i was trying to ask, sry for not really explaining what i need in detail but i guess that was my problem not understanding what i need to do etc..